# TCP/IP protocall, Android, PHP sending to and reciving from server

Tags: php, android, tcp

I want to send a message to a PHP script on a server from one android device using HttpURLConnection and have the PHP script send the message to a second phone using file.getContents().

When a phone connects with the server is it possible to leave the phone waiting for a response by not echoing a response?

Can I then later use the same connection to respond to the device by executing file.getContents() and passing in the IP address of the device that had initially connected?

Thanks!

Comment: No.  If you want to do this you either use push messaging or you use custom socket code.  You don't poll on an http connection.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan, thanks. Just reading about them now, seem handy enough!